# Recompile after converting not nullable to nullable propert

Tags: c#

I have a project which involves the following part in `MyRequest` class,

```
public int TestName {get; set;}
```

which is used by another project - let's call it as `Foo` like

```
var request = new MyRequest
              {
               TestName = mainCustomerNumber,
              };
```

After a while, I changed `TestName` to nullable type as `public int? TestName {get; set;}` and compiled the project which involved `MyRequest` class. Do I need to recompile project `Foo` as well?
**Could you tell us its reason?**

Comment: Yes you do. You changed the contract.

Comment: @mjwills could you elaborate your answer? But still an integer value is assigned to.

Comment: Not really. You changed the contract. So - it needs to be recompiled. I mean, you could try this yourself if you like. Compile `MyRequest` but not `Foo` and try and run the software. See what happens.

Comment: @mjwills I get same error. I get it exactly I need it the recompilation. But why?

Comment: @mjwills I think I have found out the answer. -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/65504458/4990642

Comment: @mjwills But your answer is really inconsequent. If the contract's a property's type is altered to long if it is int before, no need to alteration. You can check it. But not the contrary. Thus, your answer is absolutely the safe way. But not in detailed and engineering manner.

Comment: `But your answer is really inconsequent. If the contract's a property's type is altered to long if it is int before, no need to alteration.` Did you test changing the `int` to `long`? Did you need to recompile in that instance? _I ask since I don't think that will work either_. Why am I so confident? Since if it you change it to `long` then it will be able to store a long. **But it is a public property**. So now I have code that _reads_ out that long into an `int`. _Before_ the change - this was safe. After the change, it isn't. So **contract change == must recompile**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually simulate it. For the sake of the haters of `Foo` let's name the class as `Runner` which refers a library as a .dll, whose name is `Test`.
The `Test` class involves only `public int TestName {get; set;}`.

And let's expand it,

```
//public int TestName {get; set;} equals to roughly
private int TestName ;

public void set_TestName(int value)
{
    TestName = value;
}

public int get_TestName()
{
    TestName = value;
}
```

When I want to compile `Runner` class, it is turned into roughly

```
Test x = new Test();
x.set_TestName(5);
Console.WriteLine(x.get_TestName());
Console.ReadKey();
```

Now, let's change the getter-setter in the `Test` class to `public int? TestName {get; set;}` and expand it.

```
//public int? TestName {get; set;} equals to roughly
private int? TestName ;

public void set_TestName(int? value)
{
    TestName = value;
}

public int? get_TestName()
{
    TestName = value;
}
```

And compile the `Test` class. But not the `Runner` class. The `Runner` class yields the following message.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: 
Method not found: 'Void NameSpaceOfTest.Test.set_TestName(Int32)'.  <-----
   at NameSpaceOfRunner.Runner.Main(String[] args)
```

> Why?

Since the referred dll involves the setter which takes `nullable int(System.Nullable<Int32>)` as the parameter, not `int(Int32)`, the `Runner` try to find a method which takes `int` as parameter. However, `Test` doesn't have it. In the example `5` is of `int`. For its nullable version `(int?)5` should be.

Answer (score 2):

`int` and `int?` are two totally different value types. One is `System.Int32`, the other is `System.Nullable<System.Int32>`. The fact that in your source code there is a single `?` of difference only hides this diversity.

Note on opposite that if you used the nullable/non-nullable option *on a reference type* (C# 8.0) (like `string?`), you wouldn't probably need to recompile, because *that* is only a suggestion (the compiler simply put a decoration attribute on a `string` type).

See a [sharplab example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQBMQGoA+ABATARgFgAoEgYgDsBXAGxomBrgAI4KGmSTsBmZvZgGFmJAN4lmk/n2z4ADAH5mAZRgJ8zUcwDmcGAG5mUPYYC+Eqb37yVa3Jp0mjT88SnTmASwowlASR8NLV0DZ1DXdytvGGYAmHtgp2Nwi0lUj0EACgBKdPE3dylVBHsAXms5ADoAUTAABxgAT31011MgA===), right pane.

At low level (IL language), `int` and `int?` are handled in a very different way.

This:

```
public void SetInt1()
{
    Int1 = 5;
}    

public void SetInt2()
{    
    Int2 = 5;
}

public int? Int1;
public int Int2;
```

is translated to:

```
.field public valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Nullable`1<int32> Int1
.field public int32 Int2

// Methods
.method public hidebysig 
    instance void SetInt1 () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 13 (0xd)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: ldc.i4.5
    IL_0002: newobj instance void valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Nullable`1<int32>::.ctor(!0)
    IL_0007: stfld valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Nullable`1<int32> C::Int1
    IL_000c: ret
} // end of method C::SetInt1

.method public hidebysig 
    instance void SetInt2 () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x205e
    // Code size 8 (0x8)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: ldc.i4.5
    IL_0002: stfld int32 C::Int2
    IL_0007: ret
} // end of method C::SetInt2
```

It is quite clear in setting the `int?` that there is an additional

```
newobj instance void valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Nullable`1<int32>::.ctor(!0)
```

Comment: That. `TestName = mainCustomerNumber` is just syntactic sugar for `TestName = new Nullable<int>(mainCustomerNumber)` in the `int?` case. The code in Foo looks the same, but it isn't.

Comment: @Heinzi Judging by the IL code I'll say yes.

Answer (score -1):

you have two projects.
'one' has MyRequest class
'the other' has Foo

and change Type of TestName in MyRequest class

i think it's your Question.

I don't think you need to recompile if you are accessing MyReueset directly from Foo.